# Inline assembly causing symbol not found errors in gcc

Tags: gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I'm working on a fast atan2 approximation vectorized with AVX:

```
static inline void vatan2(float* __restrict__ out, const float* __restrict__ in, ssize_t npair) {
    // compute how many iterations to do and remainder of pairs left to do manually
    size_t iters = npair/8;
    size_t rem   = npair-iters*8;

    // constant vectors
    static const uint32_t posnan[8]  = {  0x7fffffff, 0x7fffffff, 0x7fffffff, 0x7fffffff, 0x7fffffff, 0x7fffffff, 0x7fffffff, 0x7fffffff };
    static const uint32_t negnan[8]  = {  0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff };
    static const uint32_t signbit[8] = {  0x80000000, 0x80000000, 0x80000000, 0x80000000, 0x80000000, 0x80000000, 0x80000000, 0x80000000 };
    static const float    ones[8]    = {  1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 };
    static const float    mpi_2[8]   = {  1.57079637,    1.57079637,    1.57079637,    1.57079637,    1.57079637,    1.57079637,    1.57079637,    1.57079637   };
    static const float    mpi[8]     = {  3.14159274,    3.14159274,    3.14159274,    3.14159274,    3.14159274,    3.14159274,    3.14159274,    3.14159274   };
    static const float    coefa[8]   = { -0.0464964733, -0.0464964733, -0.0464964733, -0.0464964733, -0.0464964733, -0.0464964733, -0.0464964733, -0.0464964733 };
    static const float    coefb[8]   = {  0.159314215,   0.159314215,   0.159314215,   0.159314215,   0.159314215,   0.159314215,   0.159314215,   0.159314215  };
    static const float    coefc[8]   = { -0.327622771,  -0.327622771,  -0.327622771,  -0.327622771,  -0.327622771,  -0.327622771,  -0.327622771,  -0.327622771  };

    __asm__(
        // load constants        
        "    vxorps  %%ymm8, %%ymm8, %%ymm8\n\t" // ymm8 = 0
        "    vmovups (%[posnan]), %%ymm9\n\t"    // abs() mask
        "    vmovups (%[coefa]),  %%ymm15\n\t"
        "    vmovups (%[coefb]),  %%ymm14\n\t"
        "    vmovups (%[coefc]),  %%ymm13\n\t" 
        "    vmovups (%[ones]),   %%ymm12\n\t" 
        "    vmovups (%[mpi_2]),  %%ymm11\n\t" 
        "    vmovups (%[mpi]),    %%ymm10\n\t" 

        // setup indices, pointers
        "    mov %[in],  %%rax\n\t" // input pointer
        "    mov %[out], %%rcx\n\t" // output pointer
        "    xor %%r8d,  %%r8d\n\t" // r8 = 0

        ".p2align 4\n\t"
        "LOOP%=:\n\t"
        // load bottom part of ymm0 and ymm1
        "    vmovups     (%%rax), %%xmm0\n\t"
        "    vmovups 0x20(%%rax), %%xmm1\n\t"
        "    add     $0x01,  %%r8\n\t"  // r8  +=  1
        "    add     $0x40,  %%rax\n\t" // in  += 16
        "    add     $0x20,  %%rcx\n\t" // out +=  8 

        // load top part
        "    vinsertf128 $0x1,-0x30(%%rax), %%ymm0, %%ymm0\n\t"
        "    vinsertf128 $0x1,-0x10(%%rax), %%ymm1, %%ymm1\n\t"

        // de-interleave x,y pairs into separate registers
        "    vshufps     $0x88, %%ymm1, %%ymm0, %%ymm3\n\t"
        "    vshufps     $0xdd, %%ymm1, %%ymm0, %%ymm0\n\t"
        "    vperm2f128  $0x03, %%ymm3, %%ymm3, %%ymm2\n\t"
        "    vperm2f128  $0x03, %%ymm0, %%ymm0, %%ymm1\n\t"
        "    vshufps     $0x44, %%ymm2, %%ymm3, %%ymm4\n\t"
        "    vshufps     $0xee, %%ymm2, %%ymm3, %%ymm2\n\t"
        "    vshufps     $0x44, %%ymm1, %%ymm0, %%ymm3\n\t"
        "    vshufps     $0xee, %%ymm1, %%ymm0, %%ymm1\n\t"
        "    vinsertf128 $0x01, %%xmm2, %%ymm4, %%ymm2\n\t"
        "    vinsertf128 $0x01, %%xmm1, %%ymm3, %%ymm3\n\t"

        // absolute values and zero check
        "    vandps      %%ymm9, %%ymm2, %%ymm4\n\t" // abs(x)
        "    vcmpeqps    %%ymm8, %%ymm2, %%ymm0\n\t" // x == 0?
        "    vandps      %%ymm9, %%ymm3, %%ymm6\n\t" // abs(y) 
        "    vcmpeqps    %%ymm8, %%ymm3, %%ymm1\n\t" // y == 0?

        // compute argument a to polynomial
        "    vmaxps      %%ymm4, %%ymm6, %%ymm5\n\t" // max(abs(x), abs(y))
        "    vandps      %%ymm0, %%ymm1, %%ymm1\n\t" // x == 0 && y == 0
        "    vminps      %%ymm4, %%ymm6, %%ymm0\n\t" // min(abs(x), abs(y))
        "    vcmpltps    %%ymm6, %%ymm4, %%ymm4\n\t" // abs(x) < abs(y)
        "    vrcpps      %%ymm5, %%ymm7        \n\t" // compute 1/max(abs(x), abs(y))
        "    vmulps      %%ymm5, %%ymm7, %%ymm5\n\t"  
        "    vcmpltps    %%ymm8, %%ymm2, %%ymm2\n\t" // x < 0

        // compute polynomial
        "    vmulps      %%ymm5, %%ymm7, %%ymm5\n\t"
        "    vaddps      %%ymm7, %%ymm7, %%ymm7\n\t"
        "    vsubps      %%ymm5, %%ymm7, %%ymm7\n\t"
        "    vmulps      %%ymm7, %%ymm0, %%ymm5\n\t"
        "    vmulps      %%ymm5, %%ymm5, %%ymm7\n\t"
        "    vmulps      %%ymm15,%%ymm7, %%ymm0\n\t"
        "    vaddps      %%ymm14,%%ymm0, %%ymm0\n\t"
        "    vmulps      %%ymm7, %%ymm0, %%ymm0\n\t"
        "    vaddps      %%ymm13,%%ymm0, %%ymm0\n\t"
        "    vmulps      %%ymm7, %%ymm0, %%ymm0\n\t"

        // finish up
        "    vxorps      (%[negnan]),%%ymm1,%%ymm7\n\t"
        "    vaddps      %%ymm12,%%ymm0, %%ymm0\n\t"
        "    vandps      %%ymm4, %%ymm7, %%ymm4\n\t"
        "    vandps      %%ymm2, %%ymm7, %%ymm2\n\t"
        "    vmulps      %%ymm5, %%ymm0, %%ymm0\n\t"
        "    vsubps      %%ymm0, %%ymm11,%%ymm5\n\t"
        "    vblendvps   %%ymm4, %%ymm5, %%ymm0, %%ymm0\n\t"
        "    vsubps      %%ymm0, %%ymm10,%%ymm5\n\t"
        "    vblendvps   %%ymm2, %%ymm5, %%ymm0, %%ymm0\n\t"
        "    vcmpleps    %%ymm3, %%ymm8, %%ymm2\n\t"
        "    vxorps      (%[signbit]), %%ymm0, %%ymm4\n\t"
        "    vcmpltps    %%ymm8, %%ymm3, %%ymm3\n\t"
        "    vandps      %%ymm2, %%ymm7, %%ymm2\n\t"
        "    vandps      %%ymm3, %%ymm7, %%ymm7\n\t"
        "    vblendvps   %%ymm1, %%ymm8, %%ymm4, %%ymm1\n\t"
        "    vblendvps   %%ymm7, %%ymm4, %%ymm1, %%ymm1\n\t"
        "    vblendvps   %%ymm2, %%ymm0, %%ymm1, %%ymm1\n\t"

        // store to result
        "    vmovups      %%xmm1,-0x20(%%rcx)\n\t"
        "    vextractf128 $0x1,%%ymm1,-0x10(%%rcx)\n\t"

        // are we done?
        "    cmp    %[iters],%%r8\n\t"
        "    jb     LOOP%=\n\t"
        "    vzeroupper\n\t"
        :
        : [posnan]  "g" (&posnan),  [negnan] "g" (&negnan), [coefa] "g" (&coefa), [coefb] "g"  (&coefb),
          [coefc]   "g" (&coefc),   [ones]   "g" (&ones),   [mpi_2] "g" (&mpi_2), [mpi]   "g"  (&mpi),
          [signbit] "g" (&signbit), [in]     "g" (in),      [out]   "g" (out),    [iters] "er" (iters)
        : MMREG(0), MMREG(1), MMREG(2),  MMREG(3),  MMREG(4),  MMREG(5),  MMREG(6),  MMREG(7),
          MMREG(8), MMREG(9), MMREG(10), MMREG(11), MMREG(12), MMREG(13), MMREG(14), MMREG(15),
          "rax", "rcx", "r8", "memory"
    );

    // finish remainder
    if (rem > 0) {
        in  += iters*16;
        out += iters*8;

        for (size_t ii=0; ii < rem; ii++) {
            out[ii] = fast_atan2(in[2*ii+1], in[2*ii+0]);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I compile:

> g++ -O3 -ffast-math -mavx -Wall -Wextra -I. test.cc -g3 -o test

I'm getting undefined symbol errors:

```
./simd.h:169:30: note: loop vectorized
./simd.h:177:27: note: loop vectorized
./simd.h:177:27: note: loop versioned for vectorization because of possible aliasing
/tmp/ccgiCMgT.o: In function `vatan2(float*, float const*, long)':
tmp/fastatan/./simd.h:162: undefined reference to `$vatan2(float*, float const*, long)::posnan'
tmp/fastatan/./simd.h:162: undefined reference to `$vatan2(float*, float const*, long)::coefa'
tmp/fastatan/./simd.h:162: undefined reference to `$vatan2(float*, float const*, long)::coefb'
tmp/fastatan/./simd.h:162: undefined reference to `$vatan2(float*, float const*, long)::coefc'
tmp/fastatan/./simd.h:162: undefined reference to `$vatan2(float*, float const*, long)::ones'
tmp/fastatan/./simd.h:162: undefined reference to `$vatan2(float*, float const*, long)::mpi_2'
tmp/fastatan/./simd.h:162: undefined reference to `$vatan2(float*, float const*, long)::mpi'
tmp/fastatan/./simd.h:162: undefined reference to `$vatan2(float*, float const*, long)::negnan'
tmp/fastatan/./simd.h:162: undefined reference to `$vatan2(float*, float const*, long)::signbit'
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: At this point, you should consider writing the entire function in assembly.

Comment: @MichaelPetch They are the static variables declared right at the top.

Comment: @fuz Doh, somehow when I scrolled through I completely missed them.

Comment: How is `MMREG` defined?

Comment: Your code does not compile even that far for me. Could you please make your example self-contained?

Comment: Figured it out, apparently the 'g' constraint isn't enough to cause the compiler to realize those symbols are used.  Changing most of my 'g's to 'r's fixes it.

Comment: Note that you can with some effort rewrite your code to let gcc do the register allocation, improving performance when this is inlined, but I strongly recommend to use intrinsic functions instead. It's just much less easier.

Comment: Also, you really don't want to put labels into inline asm. When the function is inlined more than once, you immediately get a naming collision. If you use labels at all, you should prefix their names with `.L` so they do not generate a visible entry in the symbol table and do not collide with other symbols.

Comment: @fuz: `.L` symbols will still have a problem if this is inlined multiple times in one compilation unit.  You'd want numbered labels so you can write `jcc 2f` to jump to the next `2:` in the forward direction.

Comment: @SeanMcAllister: Instead of loading constants and xor-zeroing inside your inline-asm, ask the compiler for those constants in registers in the first place  (with a `y` constraint).  If the first or last thing your inline asm does is a `mov`, you're usually doing it wrong.  (You might `vbroadcastps` the `1.0` constant, since gcc tends not to be smart about saving space with bcast loads of constants.  You should *definitely* pull the `vzeroupper` out of the inline asm and out of the loop.  (Check the compiler asm output: it should know to use it if you use `ymm` inputs to your inline asm.)

Comment: @PeterCordes The `%=` actually generates unique numbers for each time this is inlined.

Comment: I wish to state here for the record that I don't know why a comment saying "it's much less easier" gets so many upvotes.

Comment: @MrLister : the more inline assembly (which is way too easy to get wrong) you have the more chances you have to get it wrong. Using intrinsics where you can make the code easier to maintain and in many cases can allow the compiler optimizations to improve the generated code.Effectively the upvotes are that many of us who have used inline assembly for years realize that inline assembly is a tool of last resort and should be used sparingly. I think that is why such a comment got people upvoting it.

Comment: @fuz sorry for the delay in responding, can you elaborate on letting gcc do the register allocation?  I've decided against instrinsics for my particular use case.  I've got this up on CR [too](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/174617/avx-assembly-for-fast-atan2-approximation)

Comment: @PeterCordes Can you elaborate on the y constraint and broadcasting the constants?  FYI I have to support this on gcc4.4 even, so it may not know about ymm registers directly.  See my post on [CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/174617/avx-assembly-for-fast-atan2-approximation)

Comment: That's unfortunate, too bad you're stuck with such an ancient compiler. 
 However, gcc4.4 does support `-mavx`, and using an `"x"` to get an `__m256` input in a ymm register.  See https://godbolt.org/g/MeitGj for examples of all of that, with gcc4.4 and gcc7.2 output.  (Including the register allocation that @fuz mentioned)  Also with an example of loading a constant using `vbroadcastss` instead of wasting cache footprint on repeating it 8 times.  Oh, note that gcc4.4 doesn't insert `vzeroupper` for you in functions that have used ymm regs but don't return one. :/ https://godbolt.org/g/H6eRu6

Comment: @SeanMcAllister If you split your inline assembly into many small inline assembly statements, the compiler can choose which registers to use for each value and interleave your code with other code, improving performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the constraints incorrectly. From the constraint `"g"(foo)`, gcc may generate `$foo`, i.e. an immediate operand `foo` . Your operand `(%[foo])` is turned into `($foo)` which is invalid syntax but the assembler picks it up as a reference to a symbol `$foo` which does not exist (the symbol is `foo`, not `$foo`). To fix this, change your constraints to `m` to immediately generate a memory operand:

```
"    vmovups %[posnan], %%ymm9\n\t"
```

and then later

```
"m"(posnan)
```